# Multivariate regression using trax

Tags: python, tensorflow, trax

How do I set up a multi-variate regression problem using [Trax](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

I get `AssertionError: Invalid shape (16, 2); expected (16,).` from the code below, coming from the `L2Loss` object.

The following is my attempt to adapt the [sentiment analysis example](https://github.com/google/trax#layers) into a regression problem:

```
import os
import trax
from trax import layers as tl
from trax.supervised import training
import numpy
import random


#train_stream = trax.data.TFDS('imdb_reviews', keys=('text', 'label'), train=True)()
#eval_stream = trax.data.TFDS('imdb_reviews', keys=('text', 'label'), train=False)()


def generate_samples():
    # (text, lat/lon)
    data= [
        ("Aberdeen MS",  numpy.array((33.824742, -88.554591)) ),
        ("Aberdeen SD", numpy.array((45.463186, -98.471033))),
        ("Aberdeen WA", numpy.array((46.976432, -123.795781))),
        ("Amite City LA", numpy.array((30.733723, -90.5208))),
        ("Amory MS", numpy.array((33.984789, -88.48001))),
        ("Amouli AS", numpy.array((-14.26556, -170.589772))),
        ("Amsterdam NY", numpy.array((42.953149, -74.19505)))
    ]
    for i in range(1024*8):
        yield random.choice(data)


train_stream = generate_samples()
eval_stream = generate_samples()

model = tl.Serial(
    tl.Embedding(vocab_size=8192, d_feature=256),
    tl.Mean(axis=1),  # Average on axis 1 (length of sentence).
    tl.Dense(2),      # Regress to lat/lon
#    tl.LogSoftmax()   # Produce log-probabilities.
)

# You can print model structure.
print(model)



print(next(train_stream))  # See one example.

data_pipeline = trax.data.Serial(
    trax.data.Tokenize(vocab_file='en_8k.subword', keys=[0]),
    trax.data.Shuffle(),
#    trax.data.FilterByLength(max_length=2048, length_keys=[0]),
    trax.data.BucketByLength(boundaries=[   8, 128,],
                             batch_sizes=[256,   64, 4],
                             length_keys=[0]),
    trax.data.AddLossWeights()
  )

train_batches_stream = data_pipeline(train_stream)
eval_batches_stream = data_pipeline(eval_stream)
example_batch = next(train_batches_stream)
print(f'shapes = {[x.shape for x in example_batch]}')  # Check the shapes.:wq



# Training task.
train_task = training.TrainTask(
    labeled_data=train_batches_stream,
#    loss_layer=tl.CrossEntropyLoss(),
    loss_layer=tl.L2Loss(),
    optimizer=trax.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
    n_steps_per_checkpoint=500,
)

# Evaluaton task.
eval_task = training.EvalTask(
    labeled_data=eval_batches_stream,
    metrics=[tl.L2Loss(),],
    n_eval_batches=20  # For less variance in eval numbers.
)
# Training loop saves checkpoints to output_dir.
output_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/output_dir/')
training_loop = training.Loop(model,
                              train_task,
                              eval_tasks=[eval_task],
                              output_dir=output_dir)
# Run 2000 steps (batches).
training_loop.run(2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem *might* be in the `generate_samples()` generator: This yields only `1024*8` (`=8192`) samples. If I replace the line

```
for i in range(1024*8):
```

by

```
while True:
```

so that an infinite amount of samples is generated, your example works on my machine.

Since `generate_samples()` only yields `8192` samples, `train_batches_stream` only yields `32` batches of `256` samples each, so that you can only train for at most `32` steps. However, you ask for `2000` steps.